# insert new record into tables related to existing ones (key and foreign key)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert records on one table that will have new primary key on the same table and use them for inserts into another table:

I have on table 1:

```
╔════════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ id_colum (key) ║ desc1 ║ desc2 ║ desc3 ║
╠════════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAA           ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAB           ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAC           ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAD           ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAE           ║ x     ║ x     ║ X     ║
╚════════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

and in table 2

```
╔════════════════════════╦════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ id_colum (foreign key) ║ id ║ desc1 ║ desc2 ║ desc3 ║
╠════════════════════════╬════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAA                   ║ 1  ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════════════╬════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAA                   ║ 2  ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════════════╬════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAC                   ║ 3  ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════════════╬════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAC                   ║ 4  ║ x     ║ x     ║ x     ║
╠════════════════════════╬════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ AAAC                   ║ 5  ║ x     ║ x     ║ X     ║
╚════════════════════════╩════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

and I have records in both tables (50 table 1 and 200 table 2 to to give an idea of the relation), now, I have a subgroup of this records that I need to insert in both tables, so I have the table 1 that will generate the keys, and I need to add also on table 2, but using the id_colum that will come after adding into table1.
I'm trying different combinations but I'm not getting the result I need.
I tried doing a join of both tables

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id_colum = t2.id_colum
WHERE t1.id_colum IN('AAAA', 'AAAB', 'AAAC');
```

but then I'm stuck on how the insert would work for it

(to put it in short words, I need to insert new values into the tables based on values I have, but keeping the key relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

> INSERT INTO table2(id_colum, desc1, desc2, desc3)  SELECT
> id_colum,desc1, desc2, desc3  FROM table1

Comment: I don't get how this would work, the key gets generated on insert in table1, in your query there is no insert into that table

Comment: @Baldie47 Did you mean like this?
`code`
INSERT INTO table1(id_colum, desc1, desc2, desc3)
INSERT INTO table2(id_colum, desc1, desc2, desc3) 
SELECT id_colum,desc1, desc2, desc3 FROM table1
`code`

Comment: no, the values for id_colum in table 1 are generated automatically when an insert is done, I need to do the insert in that table and use the keys generated as columns in table2 

based on your query I can do:

 INSERT INTO table1( desc1, desc2, desc3) INSERT INTO table2(id_colum (generated after insert table 1), desc1, desc2, desc3) SELECT id_colum,desc1, desc2, desc3 FROM table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id_colum = t2.id_colum
WHERE t1.id_colum IN('AAAA', 'AAAB', 'AAAC');
do you get what I mean?

Comment: Ex:
insert table1:
INSERT INTO table1( desc1, desc2, desc3) VALUES ('x','x','x')
INSERT INTO table1( desc1, desc2, desc3) VALUES ('x','x','x')
INSERT INTO table1( desc1, desc2, desc3) VALUES ('x','x','x')

After insert table2
INSERT INTO table2(id_colum, desc1, desc2, desc3)
SELECT t1.id_colum, t1.desc1, t1.desc2, t1.desc3 
FROM table1 t1 
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id_colum = t2.id_colum 
WHERE t1.id_colum IN(1, 3);

Maybe I don't understand what you mean. Haha :D

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what structure of the database you already have. If you are using `SEQUENCE` for your `PRIMARY KEY` then it is really easy to do that.

Let's say you have a structure like this:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.seq_cityId START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE City
(
    CityId INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.seq_cityId),
    CityName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CityDetails
(
    CityId INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES City (CityId),
    LatestRecordedPopulation BIGINT
);
```

Then if you want to populate these tables together you can create some temporary staging table like this:

```sql
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.seq_cityId as CityId, *
INTO #StagingTable
FROM (VALUES ('San Francisco', 805235),
             ('Buffalo', 261310),
             ('Seattle', 608660)) R (CityName, Population);

INSERT INTO City
SELECT CityId, CityName
FROM #StagingTable

INSERT INTO CityDetails
SELECT CityId, Population
FROM #StagingTable
```

If you are using `IDENTITY`, that means instead of:

```sql
CityId INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.seq_cityId)
```

in your **City** table structure you have:

```sql
CityId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Then solution is a little bit complex:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO #StagingTable
FROM (VALUES ('San Francisco', 805235),
             ('Buffalo', 261310),
             ('Seattle', 608660)) R (CityName, Population);

DECLARE @OutputCities TABLE (CityId INT, CityName NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO City
OUTPUT inserted.CityId, inserted.CityName INTO @OutputCities
SELECT CityName
FROM #StagingTable

INSERT INTO CityDetails
SELECT CityId, Population
FROM @OutputCities OC
     JOIN #StagingTable ST ON ST.CityName = OC.CityName
```

Because you are inserting more than one record you cannot use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and then the best option is to use cross-reference table for these things like #StagingTable and @OutputCities in this example. In the second example with `IDENTITY` column with the name CityName is unique identifier, so for these solutions you always need to find unique indetifier.